# React router - make Link active on subroute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How to force a `Link` to be active on all subroutes?

Links looks like this

```
<Link to='/somepath' activeClassName='is-current'>Sometitle</Link>
```

And routes looks like this

```
<Provider store={Store}>
<Router history={history}>
  <Route component={App}>
    <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
    <Route component={Workspace}>
      <Route path='/somepath(/:id)' components={Component}/>
      <Route path='/anotherpath(/:id)' components={AnotherComponent}/>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
</Provider>
```

Unfortunately now `Link` is active only when `/somepath` is current location.
But it become inactive on `/somepath/356` (when some ID is selected). How to allow `Link` to be active if path **NOT STRICTLY EQUAL** to `Link[to]` property